# How can I get the SSH host key 'known_hosts' value from localhost?

Tags: ssh

Instead of doing `ssh-keyscan -H externalIpExample`, how can I generate that value directly from the localhost machine (without network access?)

I have two public keys (on one particular host) in `/etc/ssh` - are they possibly both applicable?

```
ls /etc/ssh/*.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Comment: You want another system's host key, or your own? The usage of "**external**IpExample" threw me off.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Hmm, me too.  I read 'value **of** localhost'...

Comment: The localhost's key - I mean the machine I have shell access to.

Comment: Ohhh wait...  Can I just do `ssh-keyscan -H localhost`?

Comment: Presumably they're just in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key.pub?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, and assuming that your `ssh` on `localhost` listens to port 22, then:

```
awk '{print "[localhost]:22 " $1 " " $2}' /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

will print the `known_hosts` entry.  Note that some ssh implementations obfuscate entries in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, and the above command does not.

```
# awk '{print "[localhost]:22 " $1 " " $2}' /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
[localhost]:22 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2............g7vPmspiyg=
```

Comment: This path is not present on a Nixos instance - but it's there on Ubuntu.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski What is the output of `locate ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` on Nixos?

Comment: That command terminates with a failure - exit code 1.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous, but if you want to retrieve the ssh host public keys from the machine that you already have shell access to, then (assuming you're using a borne-like shell), generally something like this would be useful:

```
ssh-keyscan `hostname -f` -H
```

... but depending on what your use-case is and how you want to refer to the host from, then you might prefer to substitute `hostname` or a particular IP address for `hostname -f` instead.

If instead you want to look up previously recorded host key entries from a known_hosts file, you could use something like:

```
ssh-keygen -F name.or.ip.address.of.remote.host -f  ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```